# Spinner doesn't show any text

Tags: android, spinner

When I click on the spinner, I can see all the elements of the array, but when I click on one of them, I can't see the name I chose. Even when the activity is created, the spinner doesn't show any default name.

The strange think is that I set the height and the width to "wrap content", after I selecting an item on the spinner, it change it size to adapt to the text, but I can't see the text.
I try to modify the simple_spinner_item.xml changing the text color to black, but nothing changed.

At this point, maybe I miss some code?

That's the method that load the spinner(I call the method on "OnCreate"):

```
public void load_spinner(){
    partecipantsArrayList = getPartecipantsList();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, partecipantsArrayList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

And that's the xml which contains the spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/partecipants_spinner"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    />
```

The spinner show the partecipantsArray element when I click on it, but then, after I select a partecipant from the spinner, it doesn't display anything as I said before. I doesn't show the toast.

Comment: where have you declared the object for spinner?

Comment: I understood the problem...the getPartecipantsList() return an empy array..I have to fix that now

Comment: check the `size` of list

Answer (score 0):

okay...where's your OnItemSelectedListener?.

```
spinnerListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
       adapterView.setSelection(i);
       // Perhaps some other logic
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, now I update my code, but again, nothing happen. it does not even show the toast

Comment: then, possibly...use AppCompatSpinner